# Como puedo evitar que mi funcion, no devuelva basura

Tags: c++

cuando ejecuto mi funcion todo funciona correctamente, hasta que imprimo el puntero y me regresa basura.
Este es mi codigo:

```
char *parsestring(string palabra)
{
    char *parse;
    new char[palabra.length()];
    //
    memmove(parse, palabra.c_str(), palabra.length());
    // se borra el puntero anterior para liberar espacio
    delete palabra.c_str();
    return parse;
}
```

Y esto es lo que retorna:

```
---------------------------------------       
Nombre del cliente: JaimitoCartero
Salida: ejemplo origenÙ
Destino: ejemplo destinocT☼▒µ´`
Tipo de pasajero: 1
No de Asiento: 8
Total al pagar: 10
--------------------------------------
Presione una tecla para terminar el programa...
```

Comment: ponle un tinaco en el código que la recoja y la tire... se llama garbage collector

Answer (score 4):

#### Problemas

Hay varios errores muy graves con tu codigo

Primero declaras un puntero `parse` que no apunta a nada.

```
char *parse;
```

Luego llamas a new, sin asignar el valor de retorno a ninguna variable (Memory Leak).

```
new char[palabra.length()];
```

Y en esta linea tenemos 2 problemas:

```
memmove(parse, palabra.c_str(), palabra.length());
```

1. Estas moviendo los datos a un puntero que no apunta a nada (Comportamiento indefinido).
2. Estas copiando los caracteres del string, pero como solo copias la cantidad que te devuelve `std::string::lenght` omites el `\0` al final del string. **Esto ultimo es la causa de que te aparezcan caracteres basura**, aunque creo que es el menor problema con tu codigo.

Y finalmente esto:

```
delete palabra.c_str();
```

Porque haces esto? El string ya se encarga de liberar la memoria en su destructor. Aqui puedes entrar en uno de 2 casos:

1. El string es "pequeño" (recuerdo que tenían que ser 15 caracteres o menos), por lo que se va a aplicar el short string optimization, llevando a que tu trates de liberar memoria que nunca fue asignada (Comportamiento indefinido).
2. El string no aplica para SSO, por lo que se le asignara memoria en el heap. Esto hará que trates de liberar la memoria 2 veces (Comportamiento indefinido).

#### Recomendaciones

Ese código es una fiesta de UB. Y la base de ello es el mal manejo de la memoria. Te recomendaría que compiles con un Address Sanitizer, ese te indicara cuando cometas errores con el manejo de memoria. (Un analizador estatico como `clang-tidy` no te caeria mal tampoco).

Además, estas en C++. Para que estas manejando tu mismo la memoria? Son muy raros los casos en los que tienes que utilizar `new` y `delete`. `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::unique_ptr`, etc se encargan de eso para que tu no tengas que hacerlo. Y si tu tienes que hacerlo, aprende lo que es RAII para hacerlo de una manera segura contra errores.

Comment: que es UB y RAII ?? fue lo único que no entendí XD

Comment: UB es Undefined behavior (Comportamiento indefinido), significa que cualquier cosa puede pasar. Con lo de RAII, he de decir que en C++ somos malisismos para los acronimos, significa Resource acquisition is initialization. Explicarlo es mas largo, asi que te conviene investigarlo.